# CentOS can I connect mobile and remotely from a laptop using another mobile connect to ssh or ssh -x?

Tags: networking, centos, hardware, wifi, roaming-profile

**Case**: I placed one rack mounted server which has only intra-network activity (do not require any kind of internet access just for the service).

**Issues**: But many times it requires remote access, in that case I need to drive from Belgium to Spain or Belgium to Portugal in the middle of the night form some tiny fix. Which is like killing issue.

**Question**: Is there any possibility to have a rack mounted server running as it is, but a simple USB or Ethernet or GuruPlug sort of device connected with the server.

Which allow GPRS-mobile protocol to PC protocol, and with that I can plug my mobile in Belgium laptop and connect Spain rack mounted server with Mobile pluged in, and use `ssh` or `ssh -x` to have same PC access feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a modem (or a cellular phone working as a modem) and pppd (point-to-point protocol daemon) configured for a dial-in.

There's a HOWTO, e.g. here: http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_dialin_server, which may help you. If you manage to make a USB-connected cellular phone to work as a serial-port connected modem (which should be possible), the rest will be easy. You could also go for a traditional modem and a landline to the box you want to connect remotely to. This would be definitely easier, but could be more expensive to set up.